# Web scraping realty webpages to DataFrame

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape web pages about flats in Prague and create a dataframe for each flat, that would show number of rooms, proce, coordinates etc.

I am able to perform basic scraping, but eventually I end up with list that I cannot filter properly.

I would like to ask for any advice, is my approach good?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

a = []
numberOfPages = 3
for page in range(numberOfPages + 1):
    url = "https://www.sreality.cz/api/cs/v2/estates?category_main_cb=1&category_type_cb=1&locality_region_id=10&page="+str(page)+"&per_page=1&tms=1583500044717"
    print(url)
    resp = requests.get(url)
    a.append(resp.json())


a[0]['_embedded']["estates"]
```

from list `a` I would like to create a data frame but using simple `pd.Dataframe(a)` return a data frame that has list inside it

is there a better way hot to perform scraping and then create dataframe with characteristics such as number of rooms, price, coordinates, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on a good way. You can extend your code with this to get a dataframe:

```
# for older versions of pandas import json_normalize like so:
# from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# use this for pandas version 1.x
from pandas import json_normalize
frames = []

for idx in range(len(a)):
    for estate in (a[idx]["_embedded"]["estates"]):
        frames.append(json_normalize(estate))

df_estates = pd.concat(frames)
df_estates.info()
```

Output:

```
Int64Index: 20 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 96 columns):
 #   Column                                              Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                                              --------------  -----  
 0   labelsReleased                                      20 non-null     object 
 1   has_panorama                                        20 non-null     int64  
 2   labels                                              20 non-null     object 
 3   is_auction                                          20 non-null     bool   
 4   labelsAll                                           20 non-null     object 
 5   category                                            20 non-null     int64  
 6   has_floor_plan                                      20 non-null     int64  
 7   paid_logo                                           20 non-null     int64  
 8   locality                                            20 non-null     object 
 9   has_video                                           20 non-null     bool   
 10  new                                                 20 non-null     bool   
 11  auctionPrice                                        20 non-null     float64
 12  type                                                20 non-null     int64  
 13  hash_id                                             20 non-null     int64  
 14  attractive_offer                                    20 non-null     int64  
 15  price                                               20 non-null     int64  
 16  rus                                                 20 non-null     bool   
 17  name                                                20 non-null     object 
 18  region_tip                                          20 non-null     int64  
 19  has_matterport_url                                  20 non-null     bool   
 20  seo.category_main_cb                                20 non-null     int64  
 21  seo.category_sub_cb                                 20 non-null     int64  
 22  seo.category_type_cb                                20 non-null     int64  
 23  seo.locality                                        20 non-null     object 
 24  _embedded.favourite.is_favourite                    20 non-null     bool   
 25  _embedded.favourite._links.self.profile             20 non-null     object 
 26  _embedded.favourite._links.self.href                20 non-null     object 
 27  _embedded.favourite._links.self.title               20 non-null     object 
 28  _embedded.note.note                                 20 non-null     object 
 29  _embedded.note._links.self.profile                  20 non-null     object 
 30  _embedded.note._links.self.href                     20 non-null     object 
 31  _embedded.note._links.self.title                    20 non-null     object 
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I run your code I get error that frames is not defined

Comment: Sorry. Its fixed now – see first line `frames = []`. Try again.

Comment: You also need to import the `json_normalize()` function: `from pandas import json_normalize` See edited answer. Be aware that the import is different for Pandas versions pre 1.x